What is a black hole island?
I have stumbled at this article about black hole islands.
It is unclear to me, what is meant.

Does it claim that the black hole's interior does not contribute the BH mass and in fact situated outside of the event horizon?

Does the BH interrior represent all of the matter outside of the event horizon or only the Hawking radiation?

Is the interior of different black holes get swapped?



The basic idea is that when you calculate the Page curve for an evaporating black hole, you're supposed to get to a point where the entropy decreases at the Page time. In Hawking's calculation (note that there are some possible issues with his calculation, see for instance Suvrat's paper on showing the Hilbert space factorisation problem with Hawking's original calculation), the entropy keeps increasing. This is the essence of the information problem.
There's ways to "solve" this in a holographic theory (in fact, I would say that this is why AdS/CFT is so popular), and one of the ways is to go from an analogue of the Ryu-Takayanagi formula (or a little more precisely, the Hubeny-Rangamani-Takayanagi formula with quantum extremal surfaces instead of a static RT surface, but both look similar in terms of extermination. I think semiclassical RT formula is a pretty calculation with the Faulkner-Lewkowycz-Maldacena paper that I really like). Usually, the generalised entropy would be something like
$$S_{gen}=\frac{A}{4G\hbar }+S_{ext}\;,$$
where $S_{ext}$ is the exterior entropy. Now, you would want to find the entropy of the radiation $R$, so you have something like
$$S(R)=\min \mathrm{ext} \left(\frac{A(I)}{4G\hbar }+S_{ext}(R\cup I)\right)\;.$$
Here, $I$ is the "island". The inclusion of the island is essentially a manifestation of ER=EPR; you end up with an additional piece in the HRT formula that you have to account for. There's some price you have to pay for this, but the upside is that you can get a pretty good return to a resolution of the information problem. There's loads of technicalities that Geoff Penington talked about in his paper on entanglement wedges and reconstruction.
I must now just say that many people view islands as being artificial. There's several schools of thoughts and many papers on this, but I would urge you to check out Suvrat Raju and Geoff Penington on Vasu Shyam's podcast, Theoretically Podcasting, on YouTube.
